# Get url from image source and launch it (UWP)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I have UWP app where I have Image with url source.

Here is xaml code:

```
 <Image x:Name="Image" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200"  Width="200" Tapped="Image_Tapped">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding data.thumbnail}" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
```

I created Tapped event handler

Here is code

```
  private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = Image.SourceProperty.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine(source);
        }
```

But it seems not right.

How I can get ImageSource and launch this url(Image source is url) in browser?

Comment: What do you mean by "But it seems not right." ? is the binding not working or you need to open the thumbnail in some viewer?

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`Launcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher) class.

```
private async void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((Image)sender).Source is BitmapImage bitmapImage)
    {
        var uri = bitmapImage.UriSource;

        // Launch the URI
        var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

        if (success)
        {
            // URI launched
        }
        else
        {
            // URI launch failed
        }
    }
}
```

Also note since you might want to decode the image to render size since you have already specified the image size (i.e. *200x200*) to save a bit of memory. You don't have to do this if you are using `Image.Source` directly.

```
<BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="200" DecodePixelHeight="200" ... />
```